# Database password not recognized wamp

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am getting a bizarre error.

I have a newly installed server on a windows 7 machine. I have set the root password using php admin, and it works well. I can log in to phpmyadmin and mysql console using the set password. But, the problem comes when I try to connect to the database using php scripts. I have placed the connection script in the www directory of wamp.

While connecting with the script, if I don't set any password then it connects successfully, but it won't recognize the databases present in the mysql server. Whereas if I try connecting with phpmyadmin password, it gives __construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I tried setting the password through 
update user set authentication_string=password('password') where user='root';

But still, works with phpmyadmin and mysql console but not with scripts.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<?php
function OpenCon()
{
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = ""; /* this works, but gives unknown database error */
$db = "demo";
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);

return $conn;
}

function CloseCon($conn)
{
$conn -> close();
}

$conn = OpenCon();
echo "Connected Successfully";
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to *the same database*…? Perhaps you happen to have another one running on a socket vs. a port…

Comment: @deceze how should I check this?

Comment: What does your phpmyadmin config file look like? Same connection settings as in your PHP file?

Comment: @deceze In config.inc.php - $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; are empty.

Comment: Instead of passing empty string for $dbpass, have you tried to pass null?
In any case, it's better to not use root as user and create another user with a password.

Comment: @Tsefo when I pass null or empty string it connects, but again it gives Unknow database 'demo' error. Whereas the demo database is already been created.

Comment: Have you tried droping/renaming the database and recreating it? Or try a different  database.

Comment: I created a new user with a password and tried with a new database as well, but result is the same. I can't connect to the server with the password but can connect it by passing an empty string or null.

Comment: But, I can log in to phymyadmin and mysql console with the password created for the new user. Strange!